# Building a password reset and web login with Parse

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

My company is using a Parse backend for user accounts & I need to build out a password reset and other web based pages that will support our mobile apps. I've not done web dev like this in a while, so I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good tutorial?

I've found some that show me how to build out the whole system (users, password reset & email confirmation)...but nothing about hooking that up to Parse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Parse provides an extremely simple solution for password reset out of the box, without the need of any plugin or mail server at all.

Something like:

```
Parse.User.requestPasswordReset("email@example.com", {
  success: function() {
  // Password reset request was sent successfully
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Show the error message somewhere
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
  }
});
```

sends a link to the concerned user.

However, the page that will open will have two important points that I like to over-write:

- It opens on the parse.com URL.
- It, by defaults, opens the Parse default template.

You can go to your app settings and over-ride the URL as well as default template, so as to suite the needs of your app and so that your users are unaware of the usage of Parse.